# Django on Docker: How to access a file from views.py

Tags: django, docker, view

I've been developing a web application under the docker environment. On that way,  the approach that views.py in the container access to an other file failed.  Following is the logs when the container named ‘web’ run

[image]

And, demo/demo_app_views.py is

```
class TestViews(TemplateView):
    template_name='top.html'

    with open('usr/src/demo/data/a', 'rb') as data:
        b = pickle.load(data)
    elder_brother=b['1']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['brother']=elder_brother
        return context
top=TestViews.as_view()
```

No matter of course, I confirmed the file ‘a’ stored on ‘data’ folder in ‘web’ container

[image]

And Dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/demo
RUN mkdir /usr/src/demo/staticfiles

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \ && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt . 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh .

COPY . . 

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/demo/entrypoint.sh"]
```

and... Docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3.7'

services:
   web:
    build: ./demo
    command: gunicorn  demo.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes: 
      - ./demo/:/usr/src/demo:cached
      - static_volume:/usr/src/demo/staticfiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./base.env
    depends_on:
        - db
    
  db:
    image: postgres:11.4-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=project_demo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=project_demo
      - POSTGRES_DB=project_demo_dev
  
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/demo/staticfiles
   ports:
      - 1337:80
   depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
   postgres_data:
  static_volume:
```

and the displaced log after `docker-compose up -d --build`

```
web_1    |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] =     self.func(instance)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
web_1    |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py",   line 127, in import_module
web_1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1    |   File "/usr/src/demo/demo/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
web_1    |     path('demo_app/', include('demo_app.urls')),
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
web_1    |     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1    |   File "/usr/src/demo/demo_app/urls.py", line 18, in  <module>
web_1    |     from . import views
web_1    |   File "/usr/src/demo/demo_app/views.py", line 27, in <module>
web_1    |     class TestViews(TemplateView):
web_1    |   File "/usr/src/demo/demo_app/views.py", line 30, in TestViews
web_1    |     with open('usr/src/demo/data/a', 'rb') as data:
web_1    | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'usr/src/demo/data/a'
web_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
web_1    |     main()
web_1    |   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
web_1    |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
web_1    |     utility.execute()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
web_1    |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
web_1    |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
web_1    |     self.check()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
web_1    |     include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 65, in _run_checks
web_1    |     issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
web_1    |     return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
web_1    |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
web_1    |     return check_resolver(resolver)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
web_1    |     return check_method()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in check
web_1    |     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
web_1    |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 571, in url_patterns
web_1    |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
web_1    |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
web_1    |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1    |   File "/usr/src/demo/demo/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
web_1    |     path('demo_app/', include('demo_app.urls')),
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
web_1    |     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import 
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
web_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1    |   File "/usr/src/demo/demo_app/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
web_1    |     from . import views
web_1    |   File "/usr/src/demo/demo_app/views.py", line 27, in <module>
web_1    |     class TestViews(TemplateView):
web_1    |   File "/usr/src/demo/demo_app/views.py", line 30, in TestViews
web_1    |     with open('usr/src/demo/data/a', 'rb') as data:
web_1    | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'usr/src/demo/data/a'
web_1    | [2020-07-04 07:52:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
web_1    | [2020-07-04 07:52:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
web_1    | [2020-07-04 07:52:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web_1    | [2020-07-04 07:52:18 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
```

I’m not good in docker, so please tell me how to access the file ‘a’, which is dictionary type file, not database

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] showing how you're building and running your container?  Can you provide these logs and error messages as text, not as screen shots of terminal windows?

Comment: Sorry, I add minimal codes & log  (are it OK ?). I hope you will provide advisable answer.

Comment: `open('usr/src/demo...')` without a leading slash interprets it as relative to the current directory, which probably isn't what you mean.  Does this work in an ordinary Python virtual environment without Docker?

Comment: Thank David. Your point is just right, being able to solve the trouble plaguing me for a few days. So I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

David's advisable comment led the answer and it is to change

```
open('usr/src/demo...')
```

to

```
open('/usr/src/demo...')
```

Thank David